# page-object gem elements count mismatch

Tags: ruby, cucumber, page-object-gem

Count returns 1 instead of actual number.

**HTML**

```
<table id='list'>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**PAGE_CLASS**

```
rows(:all_rows, css: '#list tbody tr')
```

**STEP**

```
puts @current_page.all_rows_elements.count
=> 1
```

Have no idea :(

Comment: This code works for me - ie I get 6. Is it possibly a timing issue? For example, if the table is loaded asynchronously, it is possible that not all of the rows have finished loading when you take the count.

Comment: right, I put 'code ' sleep 7 sec before the line and it returned correct number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait helped to resolve this issue. Even `Sleep 1` fixes this issue.